# Как включить песню при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript

Главное, чтобы плеер не было видно на сайте, a музыка игралась фоном.

Comment: Мне бы просто саму структуру кода узнать. Кнопка любая, музыка любая

Answer (score 5):

Допустим таким образом:

```js
let audio = new Audio();
audio.volume = .25; // Чтобы не испугать пользователя

document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.value === 'Воспроизвести') {
    e.target.value = 'Остановить';
    audio.src = e.target.getAttribute('data-url');
    audio.play();
  } else {
    e.target.value = 'Воспроизвести';
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.pause();
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="play" type="button" value="Воспроизвести" data-url="https://mp3minusovki.com/music/fhvndfjwserjgt/247bab1c312b2335afe3f5c9b496a3d3/854262e8b9de720784c0a4491e49912f.mp3">
```

Comment: @Qwertiy, не нужно "разворачивать" сниппет, я всегда его сворачиваю, даже если код одна строчка, чтобы в высоту экрана влезали ещё и ответы других пользователей.

Comment: Ну и зря. Тем более, автору стоило бы этот ответ принять - он красивее моего.

Comment: @Qwertiy, заметил, что данный автор не отмечает правильный ответ, так что не судьба)

Answer (score 5):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('audio').play()
})
```

```html
<button>Play</button>

<audio>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```